# Simple bone pulling a bow (problem)

Tags: rigging

I am making my first object in blender (a bow) its very simple started with a cube, thinned and / extruded / scaled / rotated / extruded / scaled / rotated / etc. to create half the bow about 5 pieces, I then simply mirrored if for the other half added a string then placed a single bone on the string (parent) another bone on the main bow (child) them) parented them, tested the mechanic, pulled the sting bone pulled away from the body bone okay.

Then selected the entire bow, and parented it to the bones with auto weights.  Now here is the problem.  In pose mode when I go to pull the bow string, it does pull back but instead of the string just pulling away from the bow frame, the string pulls back and the bow frame kind of pulls apart at all of its vertices. It just kind of falls apart.

I am following a tutorial that explains little to nothing other than just watching someone do it, so I don't know what he did that kept the bow in tack when he pulled the string, I tried groping the bow pieces all together but this didn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image][image]

Comment: I think you really should record the process in making it by yourself. I think something must be wrong with your workflow, which didn't quite follow the tutorial. Or, at least upload a demo file, since it seems you added additional constaints or parent something else. We do want to help you, but you need to consider my suggestion, at least. :) Try my **[sample file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27010)** for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, there are a lot of problems in your file. I'll try to point out some:

- Uncleand faces:

[image]

- Missing the two important loops here:

[image]

- Obviously, the main problem is caused by the improper vertex group setting:

[image]

While the correct settings should be:

[image]

Comment: Your pictures have helped me determine the problem but I don't know how to resolve it.  Your picture showing unclean faces that contain extra vertices I think is key.  I found a tutorial explaining that inserting a bone into an object makes it a vertices group of that bone.  So now looking at my first image I understand why the bow is fracturing at those faces its because the bow body is actually 3 pieces not one, even though it started as a single cube.  I tried "cleaning" out those extra lines or vertices to bring the bow back to one piece but only end up deleting big chunks of the bow.

Comment: Or will painting the bow with weight also solve the problem of the bow being three pieces and causes everything to bend together?

Comment: I changed the pictures up, one is me weighting it a 100 to see if it would hold it together when I pulled the string, the other picture is what happens now when I pull the string.  I did add the two loop cuts in the string.  Maybe there is something messed up with the bow model and I should just delete it and start over.

Comment: Want to thank everyone that helped me.  So my problem was that when I was creating my bow I made each part in object mode instead of adding all parts in edit mode which I guess "keeps them together".  Doing it that way allowed the bow to stay together when I pull the string back.  thank you all again very helpful people on this site!!

Comment: Also I was careful to not have any unclean faces as Leon pointed out.  I have only been using blender for a couple of days, wow there is so much to learn.