# "That Darn Bow" Problem 2

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

I worked through all the problems on my first Bow, and now have one new one that makes no sense.  No matter how I slice the string (now down to a single cut in its middle) when the bow string pulls back it only sticks to one end of the bow, sometimes its the top and other times when I redo it, it only sticks to the bottom.  I'm really puzzled over this one.  The sting ends are totally inside the bow frame.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27020

[image]

Comment: By moving the cut slightly up from center on the string it keeps the string down on each end of the bow, not sure why, but I cant have the string pulling off center, will figure it out and report back

Comment: I guess its as good as working the only thing I did different was to raise my loop cut slightly up from dead center and it seems to pull okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the weight per vertex, you can take the advantage of **Vertex Weights** panel on the right-hand N bar:

[image]

If you check, you can see the top vertices on the bow sring got non-zero weight on string bone, on the other hand, the string was parented to the bow. But the vertices on the bottom didn't have any weights. That's why it occured.

However, Other problems are still there. Because the key problem here is that the top and bottom vertices of the string need to be assigned to both bones (even with very small weights). What's more, since the bottom got no weight on any bones, they may seem fine, but actually they are not controllable by any bones, too. You'll see what's gonna happen next:

[image]

For all your issues (including your [last question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7244/696)), the poor weight assignment can be  the source of all "bugs". For such case, I highly recommend that you should not use **With Automatic Weights** operator when parenting, since it won't always behave smart enough, you need to clean and fix them manually after all. So, painting weights yourself from the very beginning can be the better way.

Comment: Your absolutely correct.  And Gandalf had eluded to this on my first post but unfortunately I didn't know enough at the time to realize that weighting could cause this so my hats off to him as well.  I have since learned allot about weighting and how to keep my bow in tack :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I guess I put this in BETA site which is why:  "put on hold as off-topic by ideasman42♦ yesterday"  Sorry!